# Geoserver dashed line Styling

Tags: geoserver, style, line, geoserver-css-module

I want to draw a dashed line on straight line

i tried but (Example)

```
* {
   stroke: yellow, red;
  :nth-stroke(1) {
     width:4,
     dasharry 5 2
   };
   :nth-stroke(2) {
     width:5;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn about our focused Q&A format. Specifically it would be helpful if you explained what happened when you implemented your attempted solution - error messages etc.

Answer (score 2):

The [CSS Cookbook](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/cookbook/index.html) shows [an example](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/cookbook/line.html#dashed-line) of this

```
* {
   stroke: blue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
   stroke-dasharray: 5 2;
 }
```